# EC2 + CodePipeline/CodeDeploy - how to make application ready on instance refresh

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Please forgive me, I am learning DevOps.

I am using codedeploy/codepipeline to deploy a node.js app onto an ec2 instance.

I am using terraform to manage the infrastructure.

The pipeline works great, but...

## Question 1: Deploy on Refresh

If I refresh the auto scaling group, then the instances are missing the application. Is this normal?

## Question 2: Clean on deploy

As a workaround in step 1, I wrote a script that downloads the latest build from the codebuild s3 bucket, unzips it, and runs the application.

I then added the logic in the ASG launch configuration to run the script.

So far, so good. When I refresh the instance, the app is booted.

However, the problem arises when I try and then trigger a codepipeline deployment.

It fails in the codedeploy step because the project folder is already full.

In my `appspec.yml` I have already tried to make it clean out the application directory during the `ApplicationStop` phase, but I have not found any success.

Any tips/guidance would be most welcome.

## Code

### app_dir/appspec.yml

```yaml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/app_dir/
    overwrite: true

permissions:
  - object: /home/ec2-user/app_dir/
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: infrastructure/cleanup.sh
      timeout: 60
      runas: ec2-user
  AfterInstall:
    - location: infrastructure/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: ec2-user
    - location: infrastructure/install_root_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 30
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: infrastructure/start.sh
      timeout: 45
      runas: ec2-user
```

### app_dir/infrastructure/cleanup.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/ec2-user
pm2 stop all
pm2 delete all
rm -rf /home/ec2-user/app_dir
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/app_dir
sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/app_dir
cd /home/ec2-user/app_dir
```

### app_dir/infrastructure/install_root_dependencies.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/ec2-user
cd /home/ec2-user/app_dir
npm install -g pm2
```

### app_dir/infrastructure/start.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/ec2-user
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/Lexstep
. /home/ec2-user/Lexstep/infrastructure/parameter_store/load_ssm_parameters.sh
cd /home/ec2-user/app_dir || exit
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/app_dir
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/logs/app
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/logs/app
sudo chmod a+rwx /home/ec2-user/logs/app

output=$(pm2 ls | awk '{print $2}')
startup_cmd=$(pm2 startup | awk '/^sudo/')

if [[ $output == *"0"* ]]; then
    echo -e "\nProcess already defined. Deleting all processes."
    pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --update-env
else
    echo -e "\nNo process is running currently. Creating a new process..\n"
    if [[ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "lexstep-prod"* ]] || [[ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "lexstep-stage"* ]]; then
        pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
    else
        pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env development
    fi

    eval "$startup_cmd"
fi
pm2 save #save current PM2 process list to start upon reboot
```

### codepipeline terraform definitions

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "codebuild_project" {
  name          = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-project"
  description   = "${var.env} Build Project for MY_APP"
  build_timeout = "10"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.codebuild_role.arn

  source {
    type            = "CODEPIPELINE"
    buildspec       = "infrastructure/buildspec.yml"
    git_clone_depth = 0

    git_submodules_config {
      fetch_submodules = false
    }
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
    privileged_mode             = false
  }


  vpc_config {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.subnets_app[0].id,
      aws_subnet.subnets_app[1].id,
    ]

    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.app_sg.id,
    ]
  }

  artifacts {
    type                = "CODEPIPELINE"
    artifact_identifier = "BuildArtifact"
  }

  secondary_artifacts {
    type                = "S3"
    artifact_identifier = "TestArtifacts"
    location            = aws_s3_bucket.codepipeline_bucket.id
    path                = "MY_APP-${var.env}-pipeline/TestArtifacts/artifacts.zip"
    name                = "TestArtifacts"
    packaging           = "ZIP"
  }

  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      group_name  = local.app_build_log_group_name
      stream_name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-app-log-stream"
    }
  }

  cache {
    type  = "LOCAL"
    modes = ["LOCAL_DOCKER_LAYER_CACHE", "LOCAL_SOURCE_CACHE"]
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.additional_tags,
    {
      Name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-project"
    },
  )
}


resource "aws_codebuild_project" "codebuild_test_project" {
  name          = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-test-project"
  description   = "Unit Test Build Project for MY_APP"
  build_timeout = "10"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.codebuild_test_role.arn

  source {
    type            = "CODEPIPELINE"
    buildspec       = "infrastructure/buildspec_unit_test.yml"
    git_clone_depth = 0

    git_submodules_config {
      fetch_submodules = false
    }
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
    privileged_mode             = false
  }


  vpc_config {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.subnets_app[0].id,
      aws_subnet.subnets_app[1].id,
    ]

    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.app_sg.id,
    ]
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      group_name  = local.test_build_log_group_name
      stream_name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-unit-test-log-stream"
    }
  }

  cache {
    type  = "LOCAL"
    modes = ["LOCAL_DOCKER_LAYER_CACHE", "LOCAL_SOURCE_CACHE"]
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.additional_tags,
    {
      Name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-test-project"
    },
  )
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "codebuild_e2e_test_project" {
  name          = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-e2e-test-project"
  description   = "Integration Test Build Project for MY_APP"
  build_timeout = "10"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.codebuild_test_role.arn

  source {
    type            = "CODEPIPELINE"
    buildspec       = "infrastructure/buildspec_e2e_test.yml"
    git_clone_depth = 0

    git_submodules_config {
      fetch_submodules = false
    }
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
    privileged_mode             = false
  }


  vpc_config {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.subnets_app[0].id,
      aws_subnet.subnets_app[1].id,
    ]

    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.app_sg.id,
    ]
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      group_name  = local.e2e_test_build_log_group_name
      stream_name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-test-e2e-log-stream"
    }
  }

  cache {
    type  = "LOCAL"
    modes = ["LOCAL_DOCKER_LAYER_CACHE", "LOCAL_SOURCE_CACHE"]
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.additional_tags,
    {
      Name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-build-test-e2e-project"
    },
  )
}
resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "codedeploy_app" {
  name             = "MY_APP-${var.env}-deploy-app"
  compute_platform = "Server"
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "codedeploy_group" {
  app_name              = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
  deployment_group_name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-deploy-group"
  service_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_role.arn
  autoscaling_groups    = [aws_autoscaling_group.app_asg.name]
  # deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime" # possible option: "CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce"
  # TODO: change this to OneAtATime for production
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce" # possible option: "CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce"

  deployment_style {
    deployment_type = "IN_PLACE"
  }

  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events  = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "codedeploy_schedule_group" {
  app_name               = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
  deployment_group_name  = "MY_APP-${var.env}-schedule-deploy-group"
  service_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_role.arn
  autoscaling_groups     = [aws_autoscaling_group.app_schedule_asg.name]
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime" # possible option: "CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce"

  deployment_style {
    deployment_type = "IN_PLACE"
  }

  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events  = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }
}
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name     = "MY_APP-${var.env}-pipeline"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.codepipeline_role.arn

  artifact_store {
    location = aws_s3_bucket.codepipeline_bucket.bucket
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["SourceArtifacts"]
      namespace        = "SourceVariables"

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn    = var.connection_arn
        FullRepositoryId = "MY_APP/MY_APP-nest"
        BranchName       = "master" # change branch here "master"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      version          = "1"
      input_artifacts  = ["SourceArtifacts"]
      output_artifacts = ["BuildArtifact", "TestArtifacts"]
      namespace        = "BuildVariables"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName = aws_codebuild_project.codebuild_project.id
      }
    }
  }

  /* stage {
        name = "Test"

        action {
        name             = "UnitTest"
        category         = "Test"
        owner            = "AWS"
        provider         = "CodeBuild"
        version          = "1"
        run_order        = "1"
        input_artifacts  = ["TestArtifacts"]

        configuration = {
            ProjectName = aws_codebuild_project.codebuild_test_project.id
        }
        }

        action {
        name             = "IntegrationTest"
        category         = "Test"
        owner            = "AWS"
        provider         = "CodeBuild"
        version          = "1"
        run_order        = "2"
        input_artifacts  = ["TestArtifacts"]

        configuration = {
            ProjectName = aws_codebuild_project.codebuild_e2e_test_project.id
        }
        }
    } */

  stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    dynamic "action" {
      # a fake map for a conditional block
      for_each = var.deployment_requires_approval ? { name = "ManualApproval" } : {}

      content {
        name      = "ManualApproval"
        category  = "Approval"
        owner     = "AWS"
        provider  = "Manual"
        version   = "1"
        run_order = "1"

        configuration = {
          NotificationArn = var.sns_notification_arn
        }
      }
    }

    action {
      name            = "Deploy"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "CodeDeploy"
      input_artifacts = ["BuildArtifact"]
      version         = "1"
      run_order       = "1"
      namespace       = "DeployVariables"

      configuration = {
        ApplicationName     = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
        DeploymentGroupName = "MY_APP-${var.env}-deploy-group"
      }
    }

    action {
      name            = "DeploySchedule"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "CodeDeploy"
      input_artifacts = ["BuildArtifact"]
      version         = "1"
      run_order       = "2"
      namespace       = "DeployScheduleVariables"

      configuration = {
        ApplicationName     = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
        DeploymentGroupName = "MY_APP-${var.env}-schedule-deploy-group"
      }
    }
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.additional_tags,
    {
      Name = "MY_APP-${var.env}-pipeline"
    },
  )

  depends_on = [aws_codebuild_project.codebuild_project]
}
```

### Terraform EC2 definition

```
#############################
####### EC2 INSTANCES #######
#############################

### APP instance Launch Configuration ###

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "app_lc" {
  name_prefix          = "app-${var.env}-lc"
  image_id             = var.app_ec2_ami
  instance_type        = var.app_instance_type
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.app_instance_profile.name
  key_name             = var.key_name
  enable_monitoring    = true
  ebs_optimized        = false
  security_groups      = [aws_security_group.app_sg.id]

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 25
    volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  user_data = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install git jq -y
amazon-linux-extras install epel -y

#############
# Node.js   #
#############
${file("gists/install_node.sh")}


#############
# App       #
#############
cat <<-'ENVFILE' | tee /home/ec2-user/.env 
export DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME="{var.env}-deploy-group"
export region="eu-west-2"
ENVFILE
source /home/ec2-user/.env

function get_app() {
  sudo mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/logs/app
  sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/logs
  sudo chmod 777 -R /home/ec2-user/logs
  sudo chmod +arwx -R /home/ec2-user/logs
  echo "get_app: starting"
  mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/app_dir
  cd /home/ec2-user/app_dir
  BUCKET="${aws_s3_bucket.codepipeline_bucket.bucket}"
  BUCKET_KEY=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
  echo "downloading app.zip"
  aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$BUCKET_KEY ./app.zip
  echo "unzipping app.zip"
  unzip app.zip
  rm -rf app.zip
  echo "removing app.zip"
  sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/Lexstep
  echo "installing root dependencies"
  bash /home/ec2-user/app_dir/infrastructure/install_root_dependencies.sh
  echo "installing root dependencies"
  bash /home/ec2-user/app_dir/infrastructure/install_dependencies.sh
  echo "STARTING APP"
  export NODE_ENV=production
  export region=eu-west-2
  bash /home/ec2-user/app_dir/infrastructure/start.sh
  sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.pm2/rpc.sock /home/ec2-user/.pm2/pub.sock
  cd /home/ec2-user
  echo "FINISHED get_app SCRIPT"
 }

mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/logs && touch /home/ec2-user/logs/get_app.log && get_app 2>&1 | tee /home/ec2-user/logs/get_app.log


echo "Finished init of app_lc"
EOF

lifecycle {
  create_before_destroy = true
}
}

### APP Autoscaling Group ###

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "app_asg" {
  name                      = "${var.env}-app"
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.app_lc.name
  min_size                  = 1
  max_size                  = 2
  desired_capacity          = 2 
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = 240
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.subnets_app[0].id, aws_subnet.subnets_app[1].id]
  service_linked_role_arn   = data.aws_iam_role.aws_service_linked_role.arn
  target_group_arns         = [aws_lb_target_group.tg.arn]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tags = concat(
    [
      {
        "key"                 = "Name"
        "value"               = "${var.env}-app"
        "propagate_at_launch" = true
      },
      {
        "key"                 = "Project"
        "value"               = var.additional_tags.Project
        "propagate_at_launch" = true
      },
      {
        "key"                 = "CreatedBy"
        "value"               = var.additional_tags.CreatedBy
        "propagate_at_launch" = true
      },
      {
        "key"                 = "Environment"
        "value"               = var.additional_tags.Environment
        "propagate_at_launch" = true
      },
  ])
}
```

Comment: Please add some code because it's hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi, @MarkoE . I've added the relevant code to the question. Thank you for taking a look.